# Detecting if something in a position already exists

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I added something to my code that's supposed to detect when an object (pixel) already exists, and then replace the color instead of creating a new one. However, for some reason, it just doesn't do anything.

Code:

```
var gridSize = 16;

var pixels = [];

var draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    for (var i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        stroke(0, 0, 0);
        line(400/gridSize*i, 0, 400/gridSize*i, 400);
        line(0, 400/gridSize*i, 400, 400/gridSize*i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        noStroke();
        fill(pixels[i][2][0], pixels[i][2][1], pixels[i][2][2]);
        rect(pixels[i][0]*(400/gridSize), pixels[i][1]*(400/gridSize), 400/gridSize, 400/gridSize);
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = pixels;
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    text(alreadyExists, 200, 200);
};

var mousePressed = function() {
    alreadyExists = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        if (pixels[i] === [ceil(mouseX/(400/gridSize))-1, ceil(mouseY/(400/gridSize))-1, [document.getElementById("color1").value, document.getElementById("color2").value, document.getElementById("color3").value]]) {
            alreadyExists = true;
            pixels[i][2] = [document.getElementById("color1").value, document.getElementById("color2").value, document.getElementById("color3").value];
        }
    }
    if (!alreadyExists) {
        pixels.push([ceil(mouseX/(400/gridSize))-1, ceil(mouseY/(400/gridSize))-1, [document.getElementById("color1").value, document.getElementById("color2").value, document.getElementById("color3").value]]);
    }
};
var mouseDragged = function() {
    alreadyExists = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        if (pixels[i] === [ceil(mouseX/(400/gridSize))-1, ceil(mouseY/(400/gridSize))-1, [document.getElementById("color1").value, document.getElementById("color2").value, document.getElementById("color3").value]]) {
            alreadyExists = true;
            pixels[i][2] = [document.getElementById("color1").value, document.getElementById("color2").value, document.getElementById("color3").value];
        }
    }
    if (!alreadyExists) {
        pixels.push([ceil(mouseX/(400/gridSize))-1, ceil(mouseY/(400/gridSize))-1, [document.getElementById("color1").value, document.getElementById("color2").value, document.getElementById("color3").value]]);
    }
};
```

Comment: I discontinued Processing.js in December of 2018. You should not be using it for new projects (instead, give p5js a try).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing arrays, you need to compare individually every item, in your case. I modified a the original example to minimize repetition of code blocks and to improve a bit speed and memory usage. You can also [a working example here](https://codepen.io/axelduch/pen/dydPrqJ)

The idea is to compare the pixels positions, encoded at index 0 for x and 1 for y. And then to compare the color channels, which are also encoded in an array so we need to then again compare individually every component.

The function `samePixels` in the following example is exactly doing that:

```
var samePixels = function (p1, p2) {
    var samePosition = p1[0] === p2[0] && p1[1] === p2[1];

    if (!samePosition) {
        return false;
    }

    var colors1 = p1[2];
    var colors2 = p2[2];

    return (colors1[0] === colors2[0]) &&
           (colors1[1] === colors2[1]) &&
           (colors1[2] === colors2[2]);
}
```

Full source code for the js part:

```js
var gridSize = 16;

var pixels = [];
var alreadyExists;
var color1 = document.getElementById('color1');
var color2 = document.getElementById('color2');
var color3 = document.getElementById('color3');

var draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    for (var i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        stroke(0, 0, 0);
        line(400/gridSize*i, 0, 400/gridSize*i, 400);
        line(0, 400/gridSize*i, 400, 400/gridSize*i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        stroke(0);
        fill(pixels[i][2][0], pixels[i][2][1], pixels[i][2][2]);
        rect(pixels[i][0]*(400/gridSize), pixels[i][1]*(400/gridSize), 400/gridSize, 400/gridSize);
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = pixels;
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    text(alreadyExists, 200, 200);
};

var mousePressed = mouseDragged = function() {
    alreadyExists = false;
    closestPixel = [ceil(mouseX/(400/gridSize))-1, ceil(mouseY/(400/gridSize))-1, [color1.value, color2.value, color3.value]];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        if (samePixels(pixels[i], closestPixel)) {
            alreadyExists = true;
            pixels[i][2] = [color1.value, color2.value, color3.value];
            
            break;
        }
    }
  
    console.log('Does the pixel already exist?', alreadyExists);
  
    if (!alreadyExists) {
        pixels.push(closestPixel);
    }
};

var samePixels = function (p1, p2) {
    var samePosition = p1[0] === p2[0] && p1[1] === p2[1];
    
    if (!samePosition) {
        return false;
    }
    
    var colors1 = p1[2];
    var colors2 = p2[2];
    
    return (colors1[0] === colors2[0]) &&
           (colors1[1] === colors2[1]) &&
           (colors1[2] === colors2[2]);
}
```

Comment: No it didn't! For some reason, when I draw a different colored pixel, it doesn't replace, but draws on top.

Comment: It is because the colors are also compared, and if not equal, it will push the new one and keep the previous one, if you want to replace them no matter the color, you can simply return the variable `samePosition` in the function `samePixels()`. This way, regardless of the new color, if a pixel was already in place, you can update its three color channels with the new pixel's colors. Does that make sense? If so, I will update the code accordingly.